# HotSpot Shiled on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I am completely new to Ubuntu and I am starting to get the hang of it. So when I was in windows I was using HotSpot Shield Elite (the Paid version) and it was working marvelously. Now I am trying to get it working on ubuntu and I haven't got a clue how too. Since I have paid subscription left for 7 more months I don't want to get another service which works with ubuntu. I was wondering if someone can help to configure it on ubuntu 14.04

Cheers

Comment: Read this thread [Hotspot Shield with Ubuntu](http://markusthielmann.com/blog/hotspot_shield_ubuntu)